# Detect selection of the same item in a DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a datagridview with a datagridviewcomboboxcell in a C# winform application.  I am easily able to capture when a new item is selected because the CellValueChanged event fires.  However, I would like to be able to detect when the combobox is opened, but the user picks the same value that was already selected.  How can I capture this?

Comment: How about the cell click event?

Comment: As far as I know combobox will fire SelectedIndexChanged event even if the item/index isn't changed at all. You can store your current selection somewhere and then compare it with user's choice.

Comment: get the old cell value into {if cellvalue is number copy into an int/short/byte variable} [if cellvalue is string copy it into a label] something you can use in your code and then compare old one and new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of the `EditingControlShowing` event and some combo box events works<sup>1</sup>.

`EditingControlShowing` allows us to access the embedded combo box control:

```
dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);


void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox control = e.Control as ComboBox;

    if (control != null)
    {            
        control.DropDown += new EventHandler(control_DropDown);
        control.DropDownClosed += new EventHandler(control_DropDownClosed);
    }
}
```

I've added a private class level variable to the form to store the combo box selected index.

```
void control_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;

    _currentValue = c.SelectedIndex;
}

void control_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox c = sender as ComboBox;
    if (c.SelectedIndex == _currentValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("no change");
    }
}
```

<sup>1.</sup> This solution fires every time the combo box is opened and closed - if you want something else (such as when the combo box commits it's change to the grid) update your question describing the exact behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try to see with event : 
 - DropDown
 - DropDownClosed